# What is the Best way to see a dataset contents in Vs 2003 IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2003

What is the Best way to see a dataset contents in Vs 2003 IDE.

I know in Vs 2005-2012 using quick watch you can see a dataset in a nice VS datagrid window.

Question is how to see a DS(DataTable) in "VS2003".

Curretly the only way I found is to add code to print the Data Table contents in the output window, which is not very convinient.

Comment: Check this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/491597/674700](http://stackoverflow.com/a/491597/674700).

Comment: Sadly the above answer only applies to VS2005 +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the *XML Visualizer 1.0 for Visual Studio 2003* from [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B-2V5dAW_9UdNmY5MGNhZTctNjdlNy00OTFlLTgyMzktZGRlNjBjZGYyNDlk&hl=en) while it's still there.

Maybe someone else will also find this link useful in the future.

Comment: Wow! Nice Man! Thank you so much!!! I have to work with this outdated VS2003 and my life is now much easier :)

Comment: You are welcome. Hopefully, this is what you need, as I couldn't test it (don't have VS 2003).