# store specific datatable data to hiddenfield in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I'm fairly new to ASP.NET and I'm trying to save a specific data from my datatable to a hiddenfield.

I am calling my datatable thru this command:

```
 SomeDetails = SomeViewBLL.GetDetails(data1.Value, Data2.Value);
```

I want to see the output of the SomeDetails variable in my console. I have tried using this tutorial:

[How can I easily view the contents of a datatable or dataview in the immediate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491555/how-can-i-easily-view-the-contents-of-a-datatable-or-dataview-in-the-immediate-w)

But it says null. However when I check my row count, it shows that it has 1 row.

Is there another way for me to see the contents of my datatable?

Comment: Check the contents for datatable after the statement is executed in next statement as you have one row.

Comment: How do I check the datatable? Do I output it in the application or is it possible for me to see it in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through the Table and code the console writing:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < SomeDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string row = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < SomeDetails.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                row += SomeDetails.Rows[i][SomeDetails.Columns[j].ColumnName].ToString() + " - ";
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(row);
        }
```