# Binding a DataTable to a DataGrid shows empty rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, datatable

I want to bind a datatable to a datagrid in wpf. This datagrid shows columns header right, the right number of rows, but rows are empty.

When i debug my datatable (with that : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18353683/4632606) i have a correct datatable:

```
--- DebugTable() ---
07/08/2014           | 
---------------------|-
0,0186               | 
0,035                | 
---------------------|-
```

And my datagrid have the correct header "07/08/2014" and 2 empty rows.

Here is my DataGrid Xaml:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="true" ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"></DataGrid>
```

What i'm missing?

**UPDATE:**
I saw that in output :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '07'
>   property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=32322646)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=07/08/2014; DataItem='DataRowView'
>   (HashCode=32322646); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Maybe an error while making the DataTable?

```
public DataTable Table { get { return this.GetTable(); } }

private DataTable GetTable()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (var controle in Controles)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(controle.Date.ToShortDateString()));
    }
    DataRow rowMoyenne = table.NewRow();
    DataRow rowEtendue = table.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        DataColumn column = table.Columns[i];
        rowMoyenne[column] = Controles[i].Moyenne.ToString();
        rowEtendue[column] = Controles[i].Etendue.ToString();
    }
    table.Rows.Add(rowMoyenne);
    table.Rows.Add(rowEtendue);
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try {Binding Table.DefaultView} ?

Comment: Same problem, empty rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the character : "/"

[What is it about DataTable Column Names with dots that makes them unsuitable for WPF's DataGrid control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2940618/4632606)

Thanks for your help.