# Simple test of DataTable.Select() is not getting any results when it should

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to test different queries on a dataset from an existing Sql Server DB.  I need to be able to grab a row by its id column for the project I am doing.  What seems like a straightforward query gets no results however.

```
DataSet prodspdata = new prodspDataSet(); 

DataRow[] load;
load = prodspdata.Tables["TripNumber"].Select("[ctripnumber] = '21605178'");

Console.WriteLine(load.Length);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output from `load.Length` is 0.  I understand from documentation that load should be an array of rows returned from the `Select()` query.  I know that this result exists from looking in the data so I expect `load.length` to be 1.

I tested a query from within Sql Server Management Studio to make sure I wasn't missing something:

```
SELECT * FROM TripNumber WHERE ctripnumber = '21605178'
```

This returns the 1 row as expected.

Is my Select query bad?  I am brand new to C#, am I testing it wrong?  I simply need to know if `load` contains any results so I know that my query works as intended.

EDIT:  So it appears my DataTable has no rows.

```
DataTable loadTable;
loadTable = prodspdata.Tables["TripNumber"];
Console.WriteLine(loadTable.Rows.Count);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This returns `0` rows whereas `loadTable.Columns.Count`gives me `133`

Did I miss a step, perhaps something to do with a TableAdapter?

Comment: It will help if you show the code for prodspDataSet

Comment: @Juan Are you specifying the prodspDataSet.Designer.cs code?  There are 8400 lines.  It was autogenerated when I added it as a data source in Visual Studio, via Project > Add New Data Source.

Comment: Are there any rows when you explore the dataset from the debugger? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491555/how-can-i-easily-view-the-contents-of-a-datatable-or-dataview-in-the-immediate-w

Comment: @Juan I found my mistake, but to answer your question:  there are no rows when I explore it in the debugger when I haven't done anything with the TableAdapter first.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not actually filled my dataset with anything, which was causing the problem.  I severely neglected the TableAdapter.  The code I added was:

```
prodspDataSetTableAdapters.TripNumberTableAdapter ta = new prodspDataSetTableAdapters.TripNumberTableAdapter();

DataTable loadTable = ta.GetData();
```

So without a TableAdapter instantiated and a table filled with the data (based on the TableAdapter's settings) you basically get an empty schema of the database with tables, columns and no values.  Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the square brackets in your filtering.

```
load = prodspdata.Tables["TripNumber"].Select("ctripnumber = '21605178'");
```

Also remember that you can use Visual Studio debugger to see the contents of DataSets and Datatables.

Comment: I've tried the column name with and without brackets, with the same result.